# Get Predecessors for BasicBlock in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, graph-traversal

What is the easiest way to get the predecessors of a `BasicBlock` in the LLVM framework?

I have taken a look at `DepthFirstIterator` and `idf_iterator<BasicBlock*>`, but I actually need to do a breadth-first search on the control flow graph.

I feel like this should be easy, but it's not obvious from the documentation or the examples I have been exploring online.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It isn't clear from the documentation, but the [basic block class](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html) has support for a pred iterator, which gives the predecessors to the basic block.  In C++11 style, one could loop through the predecessors of a block as follows:

```
BasicBlock* B = ...
for (auto it = pred_begin(B), et = pred_end(B); it != et; ++it)
{
  BasicBlock* predecessor = *it;
  ...
}
```

Comment: The BasicBlock docs are not helpful here. The logic lies in `llvm/Support/CFG.h`. I found the answer here: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-predecessors-successors-of-blocks

Answer (score 12):

A simpler way to iterate through the predecessors or successors is shown by using a for-each loop [in the Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-predecessors-successors-of-blocks):

> Iterating over the predecessors and successors of a block is quite easy with the routines defined in `llvm/IR/CFG.h`. Just use code like this to iterate over all predecessors of BB:
>
> ```
> #include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
> BasicBlock *BB = ...; 
> for (BasicBlock *Pred : predecessors(BB)) {
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Similarly, to iterate over successors use `successors`.

This is a lot cleaner than using explicit iteration with `pred_begin` and `pred_end`.